# Determine parameters accepted by GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, getcapabilities, ows

I'm looking for a way to determine which parameter arguments the GeoServer URL takes.

I can, by using owslib determine which requests I can do, but I also need to find out which parameters the GeoServer service accepts, among some examples of parameters are:

- BBOX
- srsName
- version

Answer (score 1):

The "GeoServer URL" is known as a WMS `getMap` request and is defined in the [WMS specification](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms). For example in version 1.3.0 of the WMS standard section 7.3 (page 33) gives the following table of parameters:

```
Request parameter    Mandatory/optional     Description
VERSION=1.3.0               M Request version.
REQUEST=GetMap              M Request name.
LAYERS=layer_list           M Comma-separated list of one or more map layers.
STYLES=style_list           M Comma-separated list of one rendering style per requested layer.
CRS=namespace:identifier    M Coordinate reference system.
BBOX=minx,miny,maxx,maxy    M Bounding box corners (lower left, upper right) in CRS units.
WIDTH=output_width          M Width in pixels of map picture.
HEIGHT=output_height        M Height in pixels of map picture.
FORMAT=output_format        M Output format of map.
TRANSPARENT=TRUE|FALSE      O Background transparency of map (default=FALSE).
BGCOLOR=color_value         O Hexadecimal red-green-blue colour value for the background color (default=0xFFFFFF).
EXCEPTIONS=exception_format O The format in which exceptions are to be reported by the WMS (default=XML).
TIME=time                   O Time value of layer desired.
ELEVATION=elevation         O Elevation of layer desired.
Other sample dimension(s)   O Value of other dimensions as appropriate.
```

Answer (score 1):

The request to make to a GeoServer service (and indeed any other OGC web service) to determine what parameter values it will accept is a **GetCapabilities** request.

The basic form is:

```
http://{your-service}/{geoserver}/ows?request=GetCapabilities&service={service-type}&
```

Where service type will be WMS or WFS or WCS or WPS...

If you don't specify a version in the GetCapabilities request URL, then the service will reply with the capabilities of the highest version it supports.

As you asked about `srsname` then probably you are interested in a WFS service, like:

```
http://geoserver.cprm.gov.br/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WFS&request=GeCapabilities&
```

The WFS GetCapabilities response doesn't tell you directly the names of all the parameters, you will need to read the response in conjunction with the referenced XML schema (for WFS 2.0 this would be http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd), or else read the specification document ~ https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs